# Idiom request for describing someone who is writhing in great pain

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

How do you describe someone who twist their body from side to side and bend it in reaction to a great pain? Like the men in the pictures below.

We Iranians have an expression that says:

> to twist about/ around  **like a snake** because of pain/ agony

Like in:

"After the car accident, the driver *was twisting around like a snake because of pain*, but there was no one to help him."

Is there any idiom or expression with the same connotation in English too?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Like a dying fish" is the one that springs to mind.

Comment: "Like a fish on a hook" being another take on that same pained piscine bent

Comment: Most of the time in football/soccer it's called *acting*.

Comment: Actually, most of the time when you're in great pain you don't "writhe" very much but rather do something more akin to "cringing".  Flopping about only increases the pain.  (Which is one reason why the pictured players would be suspected of *acting*, as @Jacinto suggests.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have it already: *writhing in pain* is the usual way to express this scenario, and snakes are said to *writhe*.

Although there is a general transitive sense of *[writhe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/writhe)* meaning to twist something, when referring to the human body, *writhing* is commonly used to describe the involuntary contortions associated with pain, laughter, anger, or pleasure.

One can also *writhe* deliberately, as to enjoy a warm bed on a cold morning, or to slink on the dance floor. It suggests more languid movement than [*wriggling*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wriggle) or *[squirming](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squirm)* —  snakes typically *writhe*, worms *wriggle*, and children *squirm*. But while it isn't an idiom in the sense of a figure of speech, it is an evocative word. If *writhe* appears in a news headline, one would not be faulted for immediately assuming someone is either *writhing in agony* or *writhing in ecstasy*.

*Writhing in pain* has become [much more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writhing%20with%20pain%2Cwrithing%20in%20pain&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) than *writhing with pain*, but both can be found in current usage.

Answer (score 5):

As an aside, *writhing in agony* seems to me to be even more common than "in pain" (subjective, but worth noting as also common.

Comment: Well, it seems it *used* to be, but *in pain* looks like it has become more common now. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writhing+in+pain%2Cwrithing+in+agony&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrithing%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrithing%20in%20agony%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It really depends on what / who you're reading. Some writers favor 'agony,' and others favor 'pain.'

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how intense your discomfort is?  If I am 'in pain' I can  probably still function.  If I am in agony I can think of nothing else.  *Pain* (OED) - physical or bodily suffering; a continuous, strongly unpleasant or agonising sensation in the body (usually in a particular part), such as arises from illness, injury, harmful physical contact. *Agony* (OED) - Extreme bodily suffering, often such as to produce writhing or throes of the body; severe pain.  The OP says '...great pain...'.  So I'd say 'agony' IS the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

In English, the equivalent phrase is [***racked with pain***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/racked+with+pain)

> suffering from severe pain

[The Free Dictionary]

### Usage:

> The player **was racked with pain** after colliding with the goalkeeper which fractured his Fibula.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to choster's great answer, they are *groaning in (with) pain lying on the ground*. To groan is a broadly used verb to mean:

> to utter a deep, mournful sound expressive of **pain** or grief.

[Dictionary.com]

Your example:

> The players are groaning in pain lying on the ground after getting kicked in the stomach (back) by
>   an opponent.

Comment: Well, ok, ngrams say it just crossed over...  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=groaning+in+pain%2Cgroaning+with+pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgroaning%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgroaning%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***rolling on the ground(, writhing) in pain/agony***

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=519&bih=340&tbm=bks&q=%22rolling+on+the+ground+in+agony%22&oq=%22rolling+on+the+ground+in+agony%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...27225.31120.0.31784.11.11.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..11.0.0.9Kn2A9lHRlc)

Answer (score 1):

A common expression is "***doubled over*** in/with pain" - although it is also said that someone is "*doubled over* in/with laughter."

Comment: It depends on the pain - "doubled over" is the reaction one might have from a punch to the gut (or just general abdominal pain).  A kick to the shins would not likely have the same result.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen anyone *"writhe in pain"* from a kick to the shins. Most likely, they would simply do **"the ouchy dance"**. (US)

Comment: You've apparently never watched a soccer game.  They're notorious for overreactions to pain.  (See the 2 pictures in the OP.)  At any rate, my point is that writhing in pain is generally in reference to a kind of full-body pain, while doubling over is specific to the gut area.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman-  *"You've apparently never watched a soccer game.*" You're absolutely correct... I'm a 'Murican.

Comment: -1, Neither person in the picture is doubled over. If they were doubled over they would still be on their feet.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is '*writhing in great pain*' you can say ***they are in agony*** (the point is made clearly without adding descriptions of how they are moving!).

*Agony* - Extreme bodily suffering, often such as to produce writhing or throes of the body; severe pain.(OED)

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a verb, you can use "to salmon" or "salmoning" (nothing to do with salmon).

This is named after the distinctive wiggling of salmon as it leaps through the air, when swimming upstream.